# WPF - Two identical listboxes, only one show up

Tags: wpf

Something *strange* is happening there.

I have an horizontal stackpanel containing 2 elements : two identical listboxes.

Here is the problematic snippet :

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Uxmal.Views" x:Class="Uxmal.Views.MainWindow"
Title="Test title">
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding TestControls, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}" />
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding TestControls, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}" />
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The two listboxes are (or should be) absolutely identical. They are bound to the same data source, a collection of user controls.

The constructor of the window :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        testControls.Add(new XmlElementControl());
        testControls.Add(new XmlElementControl());
        testControls.Add(new XmlElementControl());
        testControls.Add(new XmlElementControl());
    }

    private List<XmlElementControl> testControls = new List<XmlElementControl>(4);

    public IEnumerable<XmlElementControl> TestControls { get { return testControls; } }
}
```

and the simplified XAML for the XmlElementControlclass

> ```
> <UserControl x:Class="Uxmal.Views.XmlElementControl"
>     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
>     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
>     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
>
>     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
>     mc:Ignorable="d">
>
>     <StackPanel Width="500"  Height="80" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Gray"/>
> </UserControl>
> ```

But on the result :

[image]

The right pane of the window should contain the same list as the left pane, but it's empty instead.

What is happening ?

Comment: Post code for the collection as well and where is the `ItemTemplate` defined. Post that as well.

Comment: There is not template, just a user control. The list of XmlElementControl becomes the source for the two listboxes.

Comment: Your XAML is wrong, remove both elements from StackPanel and then run application, output will be same,

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. If I remove the two listboxes from the Main window's StackPane, the output is blank form. It is not the same output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is wrong, list should not contain UI elements instead it should contain data which needs to be bound to ListBox.

Problem is any **UI component can be added only in single Visual tree, you cannot add it to two different Visual trees at same time.** Here, in your case you are trying to add **`XmlElementControl`** to two different ListBoxes which definitely won't work.

Say create this test collection which return only range of numbers.

```
public IEnumerable<int> TestCollection
{
   get
   {
      return Enumerable.Range(1, 4);
   }
}
```

and create `ItemTemplate` in XAML to represent that data:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding TestCollection,
                            RelativeSource= {RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                    AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
        <local:XmlElementControl/>
     </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Declare `local` namespace at window root level, pointing to `XmlElementControl` namespace.

Comment: That's it, I was not using a data template, which is definitely the proper way to present data!